# In C++, is there to return out of a nested function that will end the parent function?

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, return, break

I want something like this to happen:

```
void a(){
    b()
    // if condition met in b(), exit out of this function also
}
void b(){
    if(condition){
        super return
        // also returns out of function a
    }
}
```

I can't seem to think of a way to do this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Throw a exception?

Comment: @songyuanyao that was brutal

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov Yes, that's why it's "super return".

Answer (score 4):

Does b has to be void? You could do it normally by:

```
void a()
{
    // if condition met in b(), exit out of this function also
    if( !b() )
    {
        return;
    }
    //continue...
}
bool b(){
    if(condition)
    {
        return false;
        // also returns out of function a
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no way in C++ to do exactly what you ask. There are 4 mechanisms provided by which you can achieve something similar.

1. Return a logical value: Return a value from b, test it in a and exit immediately.
2. Set a global variable: Set a globally-accessible flag in b, test it in a and exit immediately.
3. Exceptions: Create a try/catch block in the caller of a, throw an exception in b and catch it outside a.
4. Setjmp/longmp: Create a setjmp in the caller of a, call longjmp in b.

Those are your choices. You can write helpers or macros or templates to make them easier to use, but that's what you have to choose from.

---

Edit: deal with global and return value separately.

Please note that this is a complex topic and there are numerous traps for the unwary, including undefined behaviour using longjmp across a non-trivial destructor. Caveat programmer!

Comment: Two other choices are returning a value from `b()` - although that relies on `a()` checking the return value - and calling functions like `exit()` - which effectively return from every called function, including `main()` in order to exit the program.

Comment: N.B. it's undefined behaviour if calling `longjmp` causes non-trivial destructors to be skipped, so it can only be used in very restricted ways in C++.

Comment: Tnx: see edits. I think exit() falls outside the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in any of the following ways

1. return boolean type from the second method. in the first method check the return type then take action.

something like

```
void a(){
    if(b())
        return;
}
bool b(){
    if(condition){
        // do something
        return true;
    }
}
```

2. from the second method throw an exception. from the caller method you can catch it.